# Como implementar uma função do repositório de Pessoa para o repositório Genérico - Asp.net MVC e EF Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ddd

Tenho uma função para me retornar o maior valor de um campo ID de uma tabela usando o EF Core. Só que eu gostaria de implementá-la no meu repositório genérico para que ficasse dinâmica e para ser utilizada por todas as classes. Como faço isso?

```
//Funcionar no Repositório de Pessoa
public int GetMax()
{
  return DbSet.Select(p=> p.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
}

//Repositório Genérico
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly RetaguardaContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public Repository(RetaguardaContext context)
    {
        Db = context;
        DbSet = Db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Add(obj);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Update(obj);
    }

    public virtual void Remove(int id)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(DbSet.Find(id));
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Remove(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(DbSet.Find(keyValues));
    }

    public TEntity GetByIds(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(keyValues);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar criar uma `Expression<Func<TEntity, int>>` para que funcione a sua expressão escolhendo o campo desejado, exemplo:

Na sua classe de `Interface` crie um método:

```
int GetMax(Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> select);
```

depois implementa na sua classe concreta:

```
public int GetMax(Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> select)
{
    return DbSet.Select(select).Max();
}
```

esse exemplo da certo com o valor máximo contido em algum campo de sua tabela, mas, a expressão para `Select` tem 4 sobrecargas (`overloads`) que podem ser implementadas, mas, a que está na resposta é referente a sua pergunta.

Na utilização precisa identificar o campo que precisa recuperar o valor máximo:

***Modelo exemplo:***

```
public class Cliente 
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

---

***Código:***

```
Repository<Cliente> rep = new Repository<Cliente>(new RetaguardaContext());
var maximo = rep.GetMax(x => x.Codigo)
```

O código acima é um bom código porque também impede a digitação de campos que não seja do tipo `int`, mas, se quiser deixar o código mais genérico pode ser criado um outro método na `Interface`

```
T GetMax<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> select);
```

e implementar da seguinte forma:

```
public T GetMax<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> select)
{
    return DbSet.Select(select).Max();
}
```

e utilizar da mesma forma que o outro:

```
var maximo = c.GetMax(x => x.Codigo);
```

sendo que a funcionalidade [aumenta para outro tipos de dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables) (`int`, `long`, etc);

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [LINQ (Consulta Integrada à Linguagem)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/linq/)
- [LINQ em C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/linq/linq-in-csharp)
- [LINQ e tipos genéricos (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-and-generic-types)
- [LINQ e C#: Efetuando consultas com Lambda Expressions](https://www.devmedia.com.br/linq-e-csharp-efetuando-consultas-com-lambda-expressions/38863)
- [Building LINQ Queries at Runtime in C#](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/)
- [C# - Tipos e variáveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)

Comment: Obrigado pela Excelente resposta @Virgilio Novic!!!! Funcionou 100%